# Creating a dynamic hierarchy using PHP and ONE table - Breadcrumbs / Show Sub Categories

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy

I have a single database that contains information about categories. The table contains the following columns:

```
ID
Name
Parent_ID
```

Now, I wish to be able to display this as a HTML hierarchical list eg.

```
Home
Sports
 -- Football
 -- Rugby
Technology
 -- Phones
 -- Computers
```

I also need to be able to display any CHILD categories that relate to the parent category on a separate occasion.

For example, there are no articles within the sports category so display the football / rugby categories as an alternative.

I have tried to do this but failed miserably!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) instead. It is far more flexible than the Adjacency List Model. [Here's a link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) with a number of examples.